# Is it possible to extract/generate private key from captured SSL traffic?

Tags: ssl, https, private-key

I'm quite new so there's a deal and If anyone could help me with this i would be so grateful, 'cause I have been looking for answer since Thursday and didn't find anything : I have captured SSL traffic with several valid handshakes, containing, Server Hello, Client Hello, Certificates, Key Exchange etc. and what I tried to do was extract the SSL cert and check if I can made a valid SSL connection, ok I figured out that apparently I can't without Private Key, right? And this is my question, is it anyway to get this key from my captured traffic?

Comment: If it would be that simple then it wouldn't be very secure would it? The way ssl works is that it uses public / private key crypto to agree on a secret key, then once established, all subsequent data is encrypted / decrypted with this synchronous key. So in short, No.

Comment: @radtek You mean 'symmetric' key. And the negotiation doesn't necessarily involve PKI at all.

Comment: correct, 3rd paragraph: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: @radtek The normative document in the case is not Wikipedia but RFC 2246 as amended..

Comment: sure, the wiki entry explains the process in plain english though

Answer (score 0):

The private key should never be transmitted anywhere through an SSL channel, so no - collecting data through an SSL stream will never produce the private key.

Comment: Ok, but is it anyway i can do a valid SSL connection with that data? Can i do anything with it? And where the key is stored If i decide to retrieve it from a client?

Comment: Whoa - that's a stack of additional questions.  Without more context, it's really hard to provide a meaningful answer, but in general terms:
- No, you can't create a new, valid SSL connection with the traffic you've collected.
- The client, in many implementations, doesn't have a private key (in the public/private variety), so there's no key to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to extract/generate private key from captured SSL traffic?

No. It isn't in the captured traffic, or deducible from it.

> I can't without Private Key, right?

Right. If you could, anybody on the planet could trivially mount man-in-the-middle attacks on SSL.

> And this is my question, is it anyway to get this key from my captured traffic?

No, because it is neither in the captured traffic nor deducible from it. Neither is the session key used for encryption.

> is it anyway i can do a valid SSL connection with that data?

No.If you could, anybody on the planet could trivially mount a man-in-the-middle or replay attack on SSL.

> Can i do anything with it?

No.

> And where the key is stored If i decide to retrieve it from a client?

None of your business, but the private key is on the server. Most SSL connections don't use a client certificate/public-private key pair.